# Get a specific row from an HTML table using PowerShell

Tags: html, xml, powershell

Using PowerShell, I am reading in an HTML table, from which I need to extract certain pieces of data. SO far, I've got all of the rows read into an array $elements. I can access each row by @($elements)[rownum]. Each row has 41 cells like this:

```
 <td title="1/1/0001" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="AvailJQGrid_TARCreateDt" style="display: none;">1/1/0001</td>
 <td title="14060700421840" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="AvailJQGrid_OraRowScn" style="display: none;">14060700421840</td>
 <td title="1BC09064EF10431D9F54FEF9BA36B0A5" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="AvailJQGrid_AvailSAID" style="display: none;">1BC09064EF10431D9F54FEF9BA36B0A5</td>
 <td title="6837758D8E6542619DF23CF5EF4928C5" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="AvailJQGrid_ActivitySAID" style="display: none;">6837758D8E6542619DF23CF5EF4928C5</td>
```

Where each aria-describedby attribute is unique. Right now I iterate over all 41 cells looking for the cell I want and then grab the innerhtml or textcontent. Is there a way to access the row I want directly, rather than by iterating?

I get all of the cells with this command
$cells = $element.getElementsByTagName("td")

Is there something like $cells.GetInnerHtmlWithAttribute("aria-describedby", "AvailJQGrid_ActivitySAID")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it as XML instead, and use XPath to grab the elements you're interested in:

```
$TableRow = [xml]@'
<tr>
 <td title="1/1/0001" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="AvailJQGrid_TARCreateDt" style="display: none;">1/1/0001</td>
 <td title="14060700421840" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="AvailJQGrid_OraRowScn" style="display: none;">14060700421840</td>
 <td title="1BC09064EF10431D9F54FEF9BA36B0A5" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="AvailJQGrid_AvailSAID" style="display: none;">1BC09064EF10431D9F54FEF9BA36B0A5</td>
 <td title="6837758D8E6542619DF23CF5EF4928C5" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="AvailJQGrid_ActivitySAID" style="display: none;">6837758D8E6542619DF23CF5EF4928C5</td>
</tr>
'@

$InterestingTD = $TableRow.SelectNodes('//td[@aria-describedby = "AvailJQGrid_ActivitySAID"]')
```

Instead of `.SelectNodes()`, you could also use the `Select-XML` cmdlet:

```
$InterestingTDselect = Select-Xml -Xml $TableRow -XPath '//td[@aria-describedby = "AvailJQGrid_ActivitySAID"]'
$InterestingTD = $InterestingTDselect.Node
```